# CESIUM how to put a GLTF model with angle

Tags: 3d, cesiumjs, gltf

I want to put a 3D model on CESIUM(1.4X) with crood and angle.
I can put on right crood, but building need a angle to set on right position.

How can i to it?  Thanks

```
var modelMatrix = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(
    Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(120.9689358, 24.80441273, 32.0));
var modelG = viewer.scene.primitives.add(Cesium.Model.fromGltf({
    url : '0124.gltf',
    modelMatrix : modelMatrix,
    scale : 1.0
}));
```